# How to find bijective function between $A_l\times A_m\to A_{lm} $

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A_l=\{1,2,......,l\}$ and $A_m=\{1,2,.....,m\}$.

I know due to cardinality , there exists  bijection between $A_l\times A_m\to  A_{lm}  $ .

But I could not able to find that explicitly?

I tried by taking the product of two integers but  $(1,2)=(2,1)$.

So this also not working. Please give me some hint.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(i,j)\mapsto ( j-1)\ell+i$ is  a bijection.